# trying to get colored button by checking database

Tags: java, swing

so i was trying to get a list of buttons in a jpanel but when i compile noting happen 
this button will change color depending on the result of time.getResult() class
the frame appear empty when it suppose to show buttons in different color
thank you
every thing seem alright no errors but noting happen
here is the code

```
public t5() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    try
      {
        JButton[] label1 = new JButton[7];

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");  
            String query="select * from employes";
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
            int i=0;
            while(rs.next())
            {   
                Timer time=new Timer(rs.getString("date_de_embauche").toString());
                int j=(int) time.getResulte();

                if(j<=0)
                {
                    label1[i] = new JButton(rs.getString("id")+" "+rs.getString("nom")+" "+rs.getString("prenom"));
                    label1[i].setForeground(Color.red);
                    label1[i].setPreferredSize(dim);
                    contentPane.add(panel);
                }

                if(j<=10 || j!=0)
                {
                    label1[i] = new JButton(rs.getString("id")+" "+rs.getString("nom")+" "+rs.getString("prenom"));
                    label1[i].setForeground(Color.orange);
                    label1[i].setPreferredSize(dim);
                    contentPane.add(panel);
                }

                if(j<=15 || j!=10)
                {
                    label1[i] = new JButton(rs.getString("id")+" "+rs.getString("nom")+" "+rs.getString("prenom"));
                    label1[i].setForeground(Color.yellow);
                    label1[i].setPreferredSize(dim);
                    contentPane.add(panel);
                }

                else
                {

                    label1[i] = new JButton(rs.getString("id")+" "+rs.getString("nom")+" "+rs.getString("prenom"));
                    label1[i].setForeground(Color.black);
                    label1[i].setPreferredSize(dim);
                    contentPane.add(panel);
                }

                i++;

                //System.out.println(rs.getString("nom")+"   "+rs.getString("prenom")+" "+time.getResulte());
                //System.out.println(rs.getString("date_de_embauche"));
            }

      }
```

Comment: Are you adding buttons into panel?

Comment: well this is embarrassing how ever if any one call tell me how to make a vertical liste of jLabels instend of jButton

Comment: `JList`?  `GridLayout`?  `GridBagLayout`?

Comment: is this your complete code ?